# How to find all implementations of a Java interface, without instantiating them all

Tags: java, android, interface

I created a set of interfaces for different "data points" in my app. I want to be able to add or remove "data points" in a fairly modular way, and only load the ones that a user needs. Currently I just have one list of all of them, and I access the ones I need via an ID. I'm wanting to replace it with something that updates itself as I add implementations of the DataPointMethods interface, and that doesn't require me to instantiate all of my classes whether I need them right away or not. It's not a big problem right now, but with scalability in mind I know that it will be.

Current code:

```
private void setupMethodsList() {
    dataPointMethodsList = new ArrayList<DataPointMethods>();

    dataPointMethodsList.add(WorkoutMethods.getInstance());
    dataPointMethodsList.add(SleepMethods.getInstance());
    dataPointMethodsList.add(WalkingMethods.getInstance());
    dataPointMethodsList.add(FoodMethods.getInstance());
    dataPointMethodsList.add(WeightMethods.getInstance());
    dataPointMethodsList.add(WaterMethods.getInstance());
}
```

I *could* make a switch statement that looks like this:

```
public DataPointMethods getDataPointMethod(int dataPointID){

    DataPointMethods dataPointMethods;

    switch (dataPointID) {
        case 0:
            dataPointMethods = FoodMethods.getInstance();
            break;
        case 1:
            dataPointMethods = WorkoutMethods.getInstance();
            break;
         // TODO: add more cases each time I add a DataPoint...
        default:
            dataPointMethods = WorkoutMethods.getInstance();
            Log.w(TAG, "invalid DataPointID passed");
            break;
        // How do I just make the method just stop if the ID is wrong though? If default runs it is 100% definitely an error...
    }

    return dataPointMethods;
}
```

And while this is probably better performance wise, it's kind of a pain to maintain.

Are there any solutions to this that are more ideal? So far the only solutions I've found involve instantiating everything, which defeats the purpose...

Comment: Rather than using an int, you can pass in an enum in that switch statement.  Less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a low-maintenance solution, you can use the [`ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html) to scan your classpath to get the names of classes that implement your interface.  You can then use reflection to go from there.

```
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
            new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);

    scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(DataPointMethods.class));

    for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents("basepackage")) {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName());
        DataPointMethodsmethod = (DataPointMethods)clazz.getMethod("getInstance").invoke(null);
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to Android development, so I'm not entirely sure how using reflection would work...